# Cannot see FontAwesome Icons on Parent Window

Tags: wpf, xaml, font-awesome

Summary -- I cannot see FontAwesome icons in the designer when looking at my MainWindow.xaml view that includes a control that has the FontAwesome icons in it.

We are using Visual Studio 2012 to develop a WPF application using Simple MVVM. In our application, we use FontAwesome for most of our icons. I created a resources library that has a reference to FontAwesome (AppStyles.xaml).

Here is an excerpt from my AppStyles.xaml file that references FontAwesome.

```
<Style x:Key="FontAwesome" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Fonts/#FontAwesome" />
</Style>
```

I have created a HeaderView.xaml view that shows a toolbar of options the user can select from. Example of one of the buttons the user can click is below.

```
<Button Command="{Binding ShowStartScreenAction}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                <Label Content="&#xf015;" Style="{StaticResource FontAwesomeLabel}" />
                <Label Content="Home" Style="{StaticResource ButtonLabel}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

On the HeaderView.xaml view, the FontAwesome icons show up correctly (). A house in this case.

In my MainWindow.xaml view, I have the HeaderView.xaml view added as a control.

```
<ctrls:HeaderView Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

The problem I am having is that the FontAwesome does not show up correctly on MainWindow when I view it in the Designer, so I cannot see how the HeaderView.xaml and all my other controls look together inside MainWindow.

Here is my reference in MainWindow.xaml to my resources library where the FontAwesome reference is.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources;component/Styles/AppStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

The application runs fine, but it would be nice to be able to see what I have in the designer without having to run the application to see it every time. Can someone help?

Comment: As I remember, it had to do with conflicting styles in my AppStyles.xaml file. I stumbled on the solution by removing one style at a time until it worked and then, when adding them back in, when one broke it, I moved it up in my styles to see if it would work. Hope this helps you.